# Maintain same height and width after text('')

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

**[Fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/4M3SK/17/)**

**[Updated Example](http://jsfiddle.net/4M3SK/20/)**

Would anyone please show me how to make the table maintain the same height and width after the content is removed. I want to make sure every `td`,`th`,`tr` in the table doesn't change a bit after using `text()`to clear the content. The reason I want to do that is because a table fixed header script has some scrolling issue after injecting data from AJAX. I need to see if the change of height and width after `text();` is the cause of the problem.

My attempt would shrink a little the table on every click.

```
$('#cleartable').on('click', function () {

    var clear = $(".toptable td,.toptable th");
    var tableheight,tablewidth;
    clear.each(function(){
    tableheight = $(this).height(),tablewidth = $(this).width();

    });  
    clear.filter(function () {
        return $(this).index() !== 0;       
    }).text(''); 
    clear.css("width",tablewidth).css("height",tableheight);

});
```

HTML:

```
<button id="cleartable">Change</button>
<table class="toptable">
    <tr>
        <th class="image">-</th>
        <th class="image">-</th>
        <th class="image">-</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="description">Name</td>
        <td class="description">Alan</td>
        <td class="description">John</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="title">Age</td>
        <td class="title">8</td>
        <td class="title">9</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: first give table some height and width then try

Comment: as @M.chaudhry said first give that table some width and height and add a function to maintain it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Specify the `height`/`width` of the `<td>` elements (using the `.css()` method in this case) before you remove the text-content:

```
$('#cleartable').on('click', function () {
    // selecting the td:first-child elements
    $('table.toptable td:first-child')
    // moving to select the siblings:
    .siblings()
    // adjusting the css:
    .css({
        // i: the index of the current element over which we're iterating,
        // h: the current value of the property we're manipulating (before adjustment),
        // these names are arbitrary, and can be anything (I use these variable-names
        // simply as a matter of personal taste, to represent the property I'm working
        // with):
        'height' : function(i,h){
            return h
        },
        'width' : function(i,w){
            return w
        }
    }).text('');
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/3LC89/).

References:

- [`css()`](http://api.jquery.com/css/).
- [`siblings()`](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/).

Comment: I'm glad to have helped! Note, though, that there is some *marginal* re-sizing that happens on clicking the button; though I'm not sure why.

Comment: @user35295 not sure about your side, but I've tried using the code in this answer **in your original demo** and it still can't help. Your original demo has something **very special**. First, the `border-spacing` is gone for no reason. Second, even I've tried `border-spacing:0` on my own demo, the border seems to be thick and not smooth as yours. There is only a difference is some **external resource** in your demo, however looks like we can't remove that resource (some kind of bug in jsfiddle).

Comment: here the demo using the same code in this answer http://jsfiddle.net/viphalongpro/4M3SK/25/

Comment: I think I've found the issue, in fact this code works only when `border-collapse:separate`, if `border-collapse:collapse` is applied, it won't work. The strange thing is `border-collapse:collapse` is applied by default in the OP's code.
}

Comment: @KingKing, thanks for the heads-up. It does change a little on my site too. But it manages to maintain the height and width as close to the original table without giving the height and width to the table first so it somehow solves my fixed header issue. This is the [fixed header script](https://github.com/jmosbech/StickyTableHeaders) I'm using.